# $f \in C^1$with bounded derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I want to show the following exercise:

Assume $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ open and bounded,$1\leq p \leq \infty$, $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f'$ is bounded. Show if
$u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ then $v:= f(u)\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $\partial_iv=f'(u)\partial_iu.$

To show that $v \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ ,i have to show that v is in $L^p(\Omega)$ and also that the weak derivative exists and belong to $L^p(\Omega)$ for $i=1,...,n$.

That $\partial_iv=f'(u)\partial_iu$ is because $f$ is $C^1$ and $u$ belongs to $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ so i can apply the chain rule. Is this correct ?

Can someone help me to prove that $v \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $\Omega$ is bounded and hence f and f' are. You already have everything else established. You can use that a bounded function on a bounded set is in every Lp space and multiplication with a bounded function does not destroy Lp integrability.

Comment: For my taste, the problem is to show that indeed $v$ is weakly differentiable and $\partial_i v = f'(u) \partial_i u$, which you take for granted.